# Flutter - DropdownButton onChanged returning null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a dropdown list but whenever I click a value and try and print that in the onChanged part, it prints null, what am I doing wrong? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
  List<UserFontModel> _fonts = [
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Regular', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Bold', fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Medium', fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Light', fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Thin', fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
  ];

  String _selectedFontStyle;

    new DropdownButton<String>(
                      value: _selectedFontStyle,
                      hint: Text('Style'),
                      items: _fonts.map((fonts) => DropdownMenuItem<String> (
                        child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                          child: Text(fonts.fontFamily, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: fonts.fontWeight),),
                        ),
                      )).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String _) {
                          print(_);
                      },
                    ),
```

When I select an item I get shown:

```
flutter: null
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
List<UserFontModel> _fonts = [
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Regular', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Bold', fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Medium', fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Light', fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
    UserFontModel(fontFamily: 'Thin', fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
  ];

  String _selectedFontStyle;

DropdownButton<String>(
  hint: Text("Style"),
  value: _selectedFontStyle,
  onChanged: (String Value) {
    setState(() {
       _selectedFontStyle = Value;
      });
     },
  items: _fonts.map((fonts) {
    return  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        value: fonts.fontFamily,
        child: new Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
          child: Text(fonts.fontFamily, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: fonts.fontWeight),),
        )
    );
  }).toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

DropdownMenuItem returns it's value field. So you need to add value with child.

try like this.

```
new DropdownButton<String>(
                        value: _selectedFontStyle,
                        hint: Text('Style'),
                        items: _fonts.map((fonts) => DropdownMenuItem<String> (
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                            child: Text(fonts.fontFamily, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: fonts.fontWeight),),
                          ),
                          value: fonts.fontFamily, // add this line
                        )).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String _) {
                          print(_);
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    new DropdownButton<UserFontModel>(
      value: _fonts[0],
      hint: Text('Style'),
      items: _fonts
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<UserFontModel>>((UserFontModel font) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<UserFontModel>(
          value: font,
          child: Text(
            font.fontFamily,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: font.fontWeight),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (UserFontModel _) {
        print(_.fontFamily);
      },
    ),
```